# Is there a way I can drag a line in steema tchart?

Tags: c#, teechart

i have fastline in my tchart.

I am adding an array to fastline as a source of data.

In run time ,  fastline is drawn in tchart. now what I want to do is drag a line from particular point of it , move it up and down , etc. and as a result fastline will have changes in the data point values and the shape. Once user does that , I will get the data from fastline to array. 
Dragging function something like this. http://www.algorithmist.net/qbparam.html
so, I can control the line with mouse.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I could find kind of same thing for Gantt bars. "Gantt Mouse dragging tool.GanttTool  offers mouse interaction to drag and resize Gantt bars." but I want for line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DragPoint` tool for this.

See the example at "All Features\Welcome !\Tools\Drag Point" in the features demo included with the installation.

Here it is an example:

```
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line line1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Line();
tChart1.Series.Add(line1);
line1.fillSampleValues();

Steema.TeeChart.Tools.DragPoint dragPoint1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.DragPoint();
tChart1.Tools.Add(dragPoint1);
dragPoint1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
dragPoint1.Series = line1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have one more question. I have set my code that to chart will be full screen if user clicks anywhere in the chart , by the chart click event handler. clicking it again will make the chart window small size. I wanna disable that when user clicks on the series and tries to drag a point from the series. any inbuilt function will be helpful for me?

Comment: also I want to get values of series points into double array. I can get the data only into steema.teechart.styles.valuelist only. from there I could not convert the array into double[x,y]

Comment: @saumilpatel, this is not the proper&clearer way to ask new questions. Check if a series point has been clicked (with the series' ´Clicked()´ function) in the same chart click event to decide if you have to Maximize/Minimize the window or not. I don't understand the problem in the second question; you have XValues and YValues ValueLists isn't it? There's not a double[x,y], but it's easy to get one given these two ValueLists.

Comment: Sorry for that. I used series.clicked but it always gave 0,0 output for x,y. I am gonna use maximizing/minimizing window in double click event handler for now and for the second question , I wanted to fetch y values from the series. and save it into array of double. I found Series.YValues.Values useful. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: @saumilpatel, the problem is you are using double click with drag points that uses click method, too. This produce an incosistence, between click event and click of drag points. If you want use series clicked method,  you must use an compatible mouse event with DragPoints tool , for example, MouseDown event of TeeChart as you see:         
void tChart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tChart1[0].Clicked(e.X, e.Y)!=-1)this.Text = "Xvalue:" + e.X.ToString() + ", Y:" + e.Y.ToString();
        }
Could you tell us if it help you? Thanks.

Comment: perfect! I implemented this code and made few modifications. It is working, Thank you so much Sandra!