# Change chart values with mouse cursor in Delphi

Tags: delphi, charts

I need to create a chart in Delphi 10, where the values of the Series can be changed with the mouse. I want to press a value of the chart with the mouse cursor and drag to change its value. Is there any property that needs to be enabled or does it have a specific chart component for it?

[I saw another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967948/is-there-a-way-i-can-drag-a-line-in-steema-tchart), as shown by @KenWhite, but I did not understand it, because in that topic C# was used and the TeeChart component works differently in Delphi.

Can someone explain me how to use it in Delphi?

thanks

Comment: @KenWhite, can you help me in my edited question?

Comment: I reopened your question after looking into the other post. You're correct; that version is considerably different. Have you looked at the tutorials and guide download available from https://www.steema.com/downloads/vcl ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find attributes of component for Delphi like in C#.

Comment: I know. That's why I reopened the question. Again, did you check the tutorials and guide download at Steema.com?

Comment: A three-second search with Google turns up http://www.delphigroups.info/2/8c/397227.html

Comment: What does the word "yes" mean to you? And, what the phrase "I can not find attributes" means to you. Maybe you do not realize it, but twice in this same topic you were rude, arrogant. I see that you have helped many people and thank you for your time in trying to help me too. But I didn't do anything for you to talk like that. If you found the solution in three seconds, congratulations! But not everybody have the same habilities and that is why we are asking questions here in the forum. PS.: This link you pointed out is for the year 2001. Delphi has changed ... Thanks again!

Comment: Where was I *rude and arrogant*? I asked you to clarify a comment (politely), and did the work doing a Google search that you should have done yourself and provided you the link. The age of the link isn't really relevant; yes, Delphi has changed, but the code in that link can be adapted to what you're trying to do with TChart if you make a little effort. Clearly you're not willing to put forth any effort, but want your hand held.  I'll stop trying to help you at all. Good luck. With that sort of attitude, you're going to need it. Google "What does *Don't bite the hand that feeds you* mean?".

Comment: @wBB Note that Delphi installation includes TChart Std, but possibility to drag points perhaps is provided only in TeeChart Pro version. I think that it is possible to perform dragging in Std version "by hands" with some limitations.

Comment: Yes, MBo. I saw now. Thanks! @KenWhite, It was like I said, you do not even realize you're being rude. No one has ever told you because no one wants to create a problem with a user who has a high reputation in StackOverflow, so people simply ignore such behavior. Every day we see this everywhere, especially on the internet. And to finish, I'm not lazy! I just did not find the solution because it is not available for this version of Delphi 10 / RAD Studio, as shown in the Feature Matrix: https://www.steema.com/feature_matrix/vcl

Comment: You can stop with the personal attacks and insults. If the feature is not available, then your post is no longer needed because that feature matrix says it's not possible, and you can delete it. Then there is no issue.

Comment: wBB: you are very wrong to accuse @KenWhite's request for information and question clarification as rudeness. These requests are very common on this site, probably the most common comment you'll see, and most often folks look at them as offering suggestions that help them to improve their question and thus get better answers. If you do this, you'll do well here, but If on the other hand you're going to interpret all these requests as rudeness, then you're going to experience a lot of frustration and disappointment, and this site may not be a good fit for you.

Comment: It's not because this behavior is common here in StackOverflow that can be considered acceptable. Let's do the following experiment: the next time our boss asks us something he doesn't know, we can tell him "Again ... did you read the documentation?!" or "I only needed three seconds to solve this problem". How will our boss react? and if we did the same with our parents, brothers, friends, etc? If it's not in the interest of someone to help, that's fine. But no one needs to contempt someone who does not know something and is asking for help. We are all human and like to be treated well. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example of dragging.

[image]

I've set chart AllowPanning to False to use right mouse button freely, line series, point style is circle with size=4, and seek for touched points with simple list traversal (don't sure whether Std has methods to get the nearest point to cursor).

Perhaps you would need some limitations (for example, limit horizontal shift by neighbor values etc)

```
 DragIdx: integer = -1;

procedure TForm1.Button18Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 19 do
    Series1.AddXY(i, Sin(i/2));
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i, xx, yy: Integer;
begin
  if Button = mbRight then begin
    DragIdx := -1;
    for i := 0 to Series1.Count - 1 do begin
      xx := Series1.CalcXPos(i);
      yy := Series1.CalcYPos(i);
      if Sqr(xx - x) + Sqr(yy - y) <= 5 * 5 then begin
        DragIdx := i;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('grab %d', [DragIdx]));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  xx, yy: Double;
begin
  if (ssRight in Shift) and (DragIdx >=0) then begin
    Series1.GetCursorValues(xx, yy);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('change %d to %f  %f', [DragIdx, xx, yy]));
    Series1.XValues[DragIdx] := xx;
    Series1.YValues[DragIdx] := yy;
    Chart1.Repaint;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much @MBo. It really helped. I admit that I'm having difficulty with several things in programming because I stopped being a programmer in 2011 and I'm having trouble restarting now, as a hobby. The last time I used this feature on a chart was in 2003, with Delphi 7. Thanks again.